# What does the "same positive emphasis" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read about the consumption of milk [here](http://www.boston.com/lifestyle/health/blogs/daily-dose/2013/07/01/how-much-milk-really-need/yT8YraNS4m39XiC8RWxLgK/blog.html).

> The federal government’s dietary guidelines for Americans recommend that adults and children consume three cups per day of fat-free or low-fat milk or reduced-fat dairy products, with milk getting the **same positive emphasis** as fruits and vegetables and whole-grains. But Ludwig said those recommendations may have been influenced by the US Department of Agriculture’s strong relationship with the dairy industry.

Does it mean that ***while we drink three cups of dairy products, we have to also pay attention to eating fruits, vegetables and whole grains?***

Answer (score 1):

> What does the “same positive emphasis” mean?

The author of that article, Deborah Kotz, references the federal government's [*Dietary Guidelines for Americans 2005: Key Recommendations for the General Population*](http://www.health.gov/dietaryguidelines/dga2005/recommendations.htm).

Kotz pointed out the rather simple fact that the recommendation for drinking milk was indicated alongside recommendations to eat fruits, vegetables, and whole grains. The recommendation for milk was therefore being given a positive emphasis which was [on par](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22on+par) (of equal status) with the other recommendations. Furthermore, Kotz suggested that the milk-recommendation was not based on the science of nutrition, but rather, the dairy industry's influence within the US Department of Agriculture.

> Does it mean that while we drink three cups of dairy products we have to also pay attention to eat fruits, vegetables and whole-grains.?

***It's*** Kotz's article, and her meaning is given above.  On the other hand, the US Department of Agriculture, which Kotz referenced, suggested that drinking milk was important along with fruits, vegetables, and whole-grains.